# Using yaml src block in following python src block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, doom

I am trying to use multiple src blocks to explain a yaml config file usage in python. Below is my org file,

```
#+name: config.yaml
#+begin_src yaml 
name: john
why: check

# below is a dict example
# see it allows comments too
full_name:
  first_name: john
  last_name: smith
#+end_src

Now, let us load this into a python script
#+begin_src python :var input=config.yaml
import yaml

with open(input, 'r') as f:
    cfg = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(cfg)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

But when I do `C-c C-c`, I see `No org-babel-execute function for yaml!`. Can anyone help me identify the error and how to fix it?

Environment:
macOs, doom emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact solution, but I was able to get around with shell src block printing the yaml text which then was consumed by the python src block as a variable.

Here are the contents of my org file now.

```
#+name: config.yaml
#+begin_src sh :exports results :results output
echo """
name: john
why: check

# below is a dict example
# see it allows comments too
full_name:
  first_name: john
  last_name: smith
"""
#+end_src

Now, let us load this into a python script
#+begin_src python :var zzz=config.yaml :results output
import yaml

x = yaml.load(zzz)
print(x)
#+end_src

 #+RESULTS:
: {'name': 'john', 'why': 'check', 'full_name': {'first_name': 'john', 'last_name': 'smith'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like yaml as a language is not supported in source code blocks.
At least it is not listed in the [Languages](https://orgmode.org/manual/Languages.html#Languages) Section of the org-manual.

The error message usually means that the language is not loaded by org-babel and you have to load it in your emacs config file (.emacs or init.el) like so:

```
'(org-babel-load-languages
'((python . t)
  (emacs-lisp . t)))
```

Adding an option `(yaml . t)` did not work for me.

I might be wrong here, so correct me if I'm wrong.
I'm curious though, did execution of a yaml source code block ever work for you or is it simply not working in the context above?

Comment: Hey @Peter Bamm, Thanks for your response. I haven't tried executing an YAML source code block prior to this. I am newbie to emacs and org mode, so this is all new to me! However, I was able to get a similar version of what I wanted to work. I am adding that as an answer below.

Comment: Looks like a great workaround!